# How to get back an escaped url for ajax use?

Tags: javascript, ajax, escaping, smarty, urlencode

I've got to use smarty, and I've got to escape urls like this (I wouldn't do but I must due to some validations that don't depend on me):

```
{$ajax_url|escape:'url'}
```

But the result won't work within an ajax call:

```
index.php%3Fcontroller%3DAdminModules%26token%3Dd85497a6a2bb5cadcff677fe1d5294%26configure%3Dtestmodule
```

I tried decodeURI() but it doesn't work. I guess some solution should exist but currently I can't find. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood you want to decode your URL for the AJAX call, then simply try:

```
decodeURIComponent('index.php%3Fcontroller%3DAdminModules%26token%3Dd85497a6a2bb5cadcff677fe1d5294%26configure%3Dtestmodule');
```

Comment: It works, just did this: `decodeURIComponent("{$ajax_url|escape:'url'}")`, thank you.